# Github error add https origin but it gives me wrong ---verbose

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, error-handling, command

I have a github problem with the folllowing code. I am using ubuntu linux os.I add https origin but it gives me git://

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/PritpalSingh786/IV-View.git

git remote --verbose
origin  git://github.com/PritpalSingh786/IV-View.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/PritpalSingh786/IV-View.git (push)

I have also a push problem i.e.
git push -u origin main
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/PritpalSingh786/IV-View.git
  Use https://github.com/PritpalSingh786/IV-View.git

Please help me to solve this error
```

Hi everyone, I have a github problem with the folllowing code. I am using ubuntu linux os.I add https origin but it gives me git://

Comment: What is the output from `git config --list --show-origin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first the output of `git config -l` inside your repository:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git config -l | grep -i insteadof
```

If you see any `InsteadOf` directive, that would explain why your https URL is automatically replaced by a `git://` one.

A `git config --global --unset-all url."git://github.com/".insteadof` would remove such a configuration

Comment: I'm on a mini-campaign to get my `gr` and `grl` aliases more widely known: `$ git gr gr  
alias.grl !f() { git config --local --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f  
alias.gr !f() { git config --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f  `, so your command would be `git -C path/to/repository git gr instead`.

Comment: @jthill that is a nice alias indeed!